# how to make an anchor url via foreach using grabbed URL n TITLE

Tags: php

I use preg_match_all to grab urls and titles from another page and grabbing is ok but i cant get them in to one using foreach! or is there another way instead of foreach?

```
//gets URLs of href='xxxx'   
 preg_match_all('/a href="([^"]+)" class=l.+?>.+?<\/a>/',$sear,$results);

//gets titles of >xxxx</a>   
    preg_match_all('/a href=".+?" class=l.+?>([^"]+)<\/a>/',$sear,$t);
```

Below code Displays grabbed URLs

```
foreach ($results[1] as $url)
{
echo "<a href='$url'>$u</a> <br>";

$i++;
}
```

Below code Displays grabbed titles

```
   foreach ($t[1] as $title)
   { 
   echo $title; 
   $i++;
   }
```

but i dont know how to display them(url & title) in one foreach so i can make it like

```
<a href='URL'>Title</a>
```

I'm new to php please help me!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to combine two grabbed variables using preg_match_all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454695/how-to-combine-two-grabbed-variables-using-preg-match-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use normal `for` cycle:

```
if ( count($result[1]) == count($t[1]) ){
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($result[1]); $i++ ){
        echo "<a href='" . $result[1][$i] . "'>" . $t[1][$i] . "</a> <br>";
    }
}
```

Now this should only be used if both number of URL's and titles is matches. You should also consider matching both URL and title in the same `preg_match_all` and that way you won't need to access two array but single one... (as Brian Warshaw suggested)

Comment: yes this worls perfectly but it returns only 2 results ! before when i excicute seperatly it returened 10 results but now it only displays two links with the title!

Comment: Oh I overlooked the conditions in both `if` and `for` (forgot **[1]**). No it should work just fine. I updated the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Match them both in one expression using the PREG_SET_ORDER flag:

```
preg_match_all('/a href="([^"]+)" class=l.+?>(.+?)<\/a>/',$sear,$results, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Then you'll have two matched groups in your results array. Each element will contain an array of each match set (the manual explains this well for that flag), and you can loop through the `$results` array and then get each group from within.

Answer (score 1):

How about matching both the URL and the link display text at once:

```
preg_match_all('/a href="([^"]+)" class=l.+?>([^"]+)<\/a>/',$sear,$results);
```

Your `$results` array should now contain both matched values, in the `[1]` and `[2]` indices:

```
foreach ($results as $link) {
  $url = $link[1];
  $text = $link[2];

  echo "Link '$text' to $url";
}
```